# OpenSSL listen and decrypt automatically

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, decryption

I want to design an application to connect my server using OpenSSL and send encrypted data (encrypted with server public key) to specified port on server like 4433.

All client using server public key to encrypt data and clients didn’t need to receive any response or encrypted text, just one way connection, from client to server.

But my question is, how can I configure my OpenSSL server to listen on specified port (4433) to receive encrypted data and decrypt them automatically with server private key and insert them to my database..